# Insert an object into a JSON array in SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, syntax

Every example that I've seen for `JSON_MODIFY` shows inserting a simple value such as a `string` into an array.

Suppose I have the following JSON stored in my SQL Server column:

`[{"id": 1, "name": "One"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Two"}]`

How do I append `{"id": 3, "name": "Three"}` to it?

When I try using `JSON_MODIFY` as shown below, a `string` is inserted:

`UPDATE TheTable SET TheJSON = JSON_MODIFY(TheJSON, 'append $', N'{"id": 3, "name": "Three"}') WHERE Condition = 1;`

Here is the resulting value for `TheJSON` column:

`[{"id": 1, "name": "One"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Two"}, "{\"id\":3, \"name\": \"Three\"}"]`

#### Other Attempts:

I noticed that I can create the JSON string that I want like this:

```
SELECT json.*
FROM TheTable t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.TheJSON) WITH (
    id int N'$.id',
    name nvarchar(100) N'$.name'
)
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 as id, N'Three' as name
FOR JSON AUTO;
```

However, when I go to try and use it in an update statement, it doesn't work:

```
UPDATE TheTable
SET TheJSON = (
    SELECT json.* FROM TheTable t
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.TheJSON) WITH (
        id int N'$.id',
        name nvarchar(100) N'$.name'
    ) as json
    UNION ALL -- NO ERROR (and no update) when I remove UNION ALL+SELECT
    SELECT 3 as id, N'Three' as name
    FOR JSON AUTO
);
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 1086, Level 15, State 1, Line 1: The FOR XML and FOR JSON clauses are invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, and subqueries when they contain a set operator. To work around, wrap the SELECT containing a set operator using derived table or common table expression or view and apply FOR XML or FOR JSON on top of it.

Comment: I suppose that I could just use a table-variable to hold my JSON data temporarily, insert into it and then select from that with `FOR JSON` ~ I tried just that and it worked fine. So, I will watch this question to see if there is an even simpler method.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You should wrap the third parameter of your `JSON_MODIFY` statement with `JSON_QUERY()`:

```
UPDATE TheTable 
SET TheJSON = JSON_MODIFY(TheJSON, 'append $', JSON_QUERY(N'{"id": 3, "name": "Three"}')) 
WHERE Condition = 1;
```

Here is a complete sample:

```
DECLARE @TheTable table(TheJSON nvarchar(max), Condition int )
DECLARE @mystring nvarchar(100)='{"id": 3, "name": "Three"}'

INSERT INTO @TheTable SELECT '[{"id": 1, "name": "One"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Two"}]', 1

UPDATE @TheTable 
SET TheJSON = JSON_MODIFY(TheJSON, 'append $', JSON_QUERY(N'{"id": 3, "name": "Three"}')) 
WHERE Condition = 1;

SELECT TheJSON FROM @TheTable
```

This is the final output:

```
[{"id": 1, "name": "One"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Two"},{"id": 3, "name": "Three"}]
```

More info on `JSON_QUERY` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql), and the explanation of the issue is [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2017/12/22/injecting-json-objects-into-existing-json-text-with-json_modify-function/).