# Bulk insert of JSON arrays into SQL Server tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is the sample with input:

```
{
    "OUTER": {
                "ABC":"TEST_WB_New","XYZ":"9085"
             },
             {
                "ABC":"TEST_WB1_New","XYZ":"9086"
             },
             {
                "ABC":"TEST_WB2_New","XYZ":"9087"
             }
}
```

I want this to be inserted into two columns row by row

My attempt so far:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (ABC, XYZ) 
    SELECT ABC, XYZ 
    FROM OPENJSON(@json) 
    WITH (ABC NVARCHAR(50), XYZ NVARCHAR(50))
```

Comment: **SHOW US** your current efforts ! We'll help - but we won't just write the whole code for you .....

Comment: @marc_s INSERT INTO my_table (ABC , XYZ )
SELECT ABC ,XYZ 
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
     WITH (ABC nvarchar(50), XYZ nvarchar(50))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert an object into a JSON array in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47917009/insert-an-object-into-a-json-array-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, notice '[]' array brackets in json input string and '$.OUTER' in OPENJSON function.

```
    DECLARE @JSONINPUT nvarchar(4000) =
    '{
        "OUTER": [{
                    "ABC":"TEST_WB_New","XYZ":"9085"
                 },
                 {
                    "ABC":"TEST_WB1_New","XYZ":"9086"
                 },
                 {
                    "ABC":"TEST_WB2_New","XYZ":"9087"
                 }]
    }';

    SELECT ABC, XYZ 
    FROM OPENJSON(@JSONINPUT,'$.OUTER') 
    WITH (ABC NVARCHAR(50), XYZ NVARCHAR(50))
```